# Will it blend? Starting to think this is not possible at all

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, rendering, xna-4.0

I'm stuck for several days now. What I'm trying to achieve shouldn't be that hard, but I cannot figure it out.

[image]

I want to blend two sprites together and only get the overlapping part as a result (the blue part in the image). The limitation that I have is it must be under the Reach-profile (limited blending options and no shaders). Because of that I cannot figure out how to blend both sprites to get the result.

I do have stencilmasks for both sprites and the white in the image is transparent (and should also be transparent in the resulting image).

This is the code I have so far:

```
//Set the render target
spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(rtFinal);

//Clear the renderTarget
spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent); //I need transparent result

//Clear the stencil's buffer
spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Stencil, Color.White, 0, 0);

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Additive); //Adding the two sprites together

spriteBatch.Draw((rtCutOut as Texture2D), Vector2.Zero, Color.White); //Unsure about this color
spriteBatch.Draw(ent.StencilTex, Vector2.Zero, Color.Blue); //Using the other stencil

spriteBatch.End();
```

This code results in (not what I want):

[image]

I do understand why I get this result (because it's just an additive render), but I don't know how to get it right (cutting of the non-overlapping parts).

I can also get the following result:

[image: http://i43.tinypic.com/2d9tz7n.png]

But that's with one of the stencils using a white background instead of a transparent one.

Please help, before I lose my sanity...

Comment: Please edit the question to provide details of what you've tried so far and exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've added more details and pictures of my results, but unfortunately no answers yet, I'm starting to think this is not possible at all on a Windows Phone in XNA